# What programming languages should a college student put on his resume

Tags: programming-languages

I have put almost all the programming languages I have worked with on my resume, while I am only proficient in Java.

Comment: This belongs in "Programmers" imo.

Comment: hmmm.. i searched "languages resume" and saw open posts before I made this post.

Comment: You will probably get much better answers if you head over to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ and post the question there.

Comment: @Tudor Thanks I will try that as well. Never really know that site

Comment: @Tudor - this question would get closed on Programmers as not constructive at best. Have you read our [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) recently?

Comment: @ChrisF: Well if I'd have to pick, it would be closer to Programmers definitely than SO, even though it's also inappropriate there.

Comment: @Tudor - You don't have to pick. The simplest solution is to close as  not constructive. If in doubt, don't migrate.

Comment: @ChrisF: Sorry, I voted to close it as you can see below, I don't know what happened to it afterwards. I didn't migrate it myself.

Comment: @Tudor - I addressed you as you suggested migration in your comment. No one can find out how you actually voted.

Answer (score 3):

I would split the programming languages into **Basic** and **Intermediate** sections if you know some languages better than the other.

The last thing you want is the interviewer asking you some esoteric question about a language that you only know basics of and judge you for it.

Comment: Didn't the "(best)" note after Java serve this purpose? Or is it not that obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Well, just tell the truth. If you have an experience in C++, tell them. Be honest and don't be afraid to say you're a bit rusty with the syntax, that's it.

Anyway, if they ask you to program an algorithm live, most of the time you can do it in the language you prefer, even pseudo-code (according to my experiences).

Comment: I'm just a little bit worried that they will ask me to code in C, since it's quite common and I put C on my resume. But I only had one course in C and that's it.